# trouble with cake.bat

Tags: cakephp, windows-shell

I am new to php and cake php. I am attempting to bake up some cakephp code in the Windows Command Prompt. When I do the command "cake bake" within C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\lib\Cake\Console, I get no result, just a blinking cursor. Has anyone else ever had this happen or have any suggestions that might be helpful?

Comment: see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/03/console-for-cakephp/ - most is still valid for 2.x - also always execute the cake shells from your APP directory!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the dir `C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\app`.

Comment: I get the same behavior from the app folder

Comment: Then the console is badly installed. Go there:http://www.nurelm.com/themanual/2012/01/30/running-cakephp-command-line-tools-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Windows you have. However, you must access **Environment Variables** Access it by any mean.
In Windows7:
Right Click on Mycomputer-> Properties -> click on Advanced System Settings -> The last button Environment Variables is there, click on it From System Variables list select Path and then press Edit button. You will see a line of code, at its end add something like the following:

```
;C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\cake\console\;C:\xampp\php
```

The first path is the path in-which cake.bat file is found
The second path is the path in-which php.exe is found.

Restart your coputer and you will find cake bake works fine at any directory you want.

Comment: My answer offers reusable and continuous solution, look in the last line of my answer.